# Assumptions for robust linear regression, specifically ANCOVA type models

Tags: regression, ancova, robust, assumptions

I have started looking into robust methods of data analysis. In particular, robust regression methods for ANCOVA type models using the *"lmRob"* function from the *"robust"* library in R. I'm having a hard time finding what assumptions I need to satisfy in order to use this. I've read that they can be useful in situations where there are outliers, heterogeneity of variance and for non-normal distributions, i.e., [http://psych.colorado.edu/~willcutt/res_meth/Wilcox_1998.pdf](http://psych.colorado.edu/%7Ewillcutt/res_meth/Wilcox_1998.pdf) (more recently [Link](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-5525-8_11?from=SL)). However, I'm unsure of how much departure robust measures will allow for and what other *traps* might be awaiting me.
References and/or examples will be much appreciated.

Data description:
sample size ~  1000, differs substantially between groups
1st factor has 3 levels; 2nd factor has 3 levels
3 covariates, 1 of which is related to both factors, 1 related to only one factor

The model I'm especially interested in examining is something like this:

```
lmr1 <- lmRob(dv ~ cov1 + cov2 + cov3 + fac1 * fac2, data)
```

Comment: That the residuals from the *good* part of the data are approximately symmetric, other than that you're safe! PS: you might wanna link to a more recent article, there as been gigantic leaps in computational tractability in this filed in the last 10 years (specially in higher dimensions)....

Comment: Thanks. Will look for a more recent paper to update the question.